# How do I retrieve the available commands from a module?

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-2.0

To know which PowerShell modules are available on a machine I use the command

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

This returns a list with module-type, -name and the exported commands. But the exported commands are always empty and just displaying `{}`. Why is this not displayed?

Do I have to use another parameter or is there another cmdlet or method to retrieve the available commands?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Exported commands are not available if the module is not loaded. You need to load the module first and then execute [Get-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Command):

```
Import-Module -Name <ModuleName>
Get-Command -Module <ModuleName>
```

Answer (score 22):

Use the parameter `-ListAvailable`

```
Get-Module <moduleName> -ListAvailable | % { $_.ExportedCommands.Values }
```

"`<moduleName>`" is optional. Omit to show all available modules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations.

Comment: My question is a bit outdated. But your reply does not work for powershell 2 because the property "ExportedCommands" is empty. Your code works properly for powershell 4 and 5.

Answer (score 4):

[enter image description here][1]In the meantime this command here answers the question:

```
Get-Command -Module <#Your Module#>
```

Pretty simple...

Here the Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bITl0.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31747961)

Answer (score 0):

This will List all the commands under a module and search through them:

```
Get-Command -Module dbatools| ?{$_.name -match 'service'}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### PowerShell 2.0 - this works for me:

```
Get-Module <moduleName> | % {$_.ExportedCommands.Values}
```

#### To list the loaded modules in the current session:

```
Get-Module
```

Comment: Shay Levy answered that question years ago. You gave no new input.