# Calling a function within module / Powershell

Tags: powershell

I must be missing something basic here, but i'm new to powershell...

I wrote a function and saved it in a file called "UserSelectionList.psm1",  the function is stubbed out like this:

```
function Global:UserSelectionList([String[]] $UserOptions)
{
...
}
```

i then try to call it with this script:

```
Import-module "l:\support downstream\solarc\cngl\powershell scripts\userselectionlist.psm1"
$Options = "a","b","c"
cls
$result = UserSelectionList $Options
echo $result
```

The resulting error is:

```
The term 'UserSelectionList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:28
+ $result = UserSelectionList <<<<  $Options
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (UserSelectionList:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm planning to have more than one function in a module, but this is where I'm at.

thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't seem right, perhaps a typo somewhere... After importing the module, what is the result of running `Get-Module userselectionlist`  and `Get-Item Function:\UserSelectionList` ?

Comment: Get-Module UserSelectionList yields:PS L:\Support Downstream\Solarc\CNGL\Powershell Scripts> Get-Module userselectionlist 

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands                                                           
---------- ----                      ----------------                                                           
Script     userselectionlist         {}

Comment: Get-Item Function: errors out with "Cannot find path 'Function:\UserSelectionList' because it does not exist."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edit] I was not doing a Import Module with a -Force option.  The answer below is incorrect, but perhaps the Get-Command forced a refresh?  Either way, I'm leaving it for completeness of the experience!

Thanks to latkin for pushing me to another path where i found this:

[How do I retrieve command from a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354317/how-do-i-retrieve-the-available-commands-from-a-module)

Not only do you have to import a module, you then have to "get" it as well (?)

```
Import-Module -Name <ModuleName> 
Get-Command -Module <ModuleName>
```

After I issued the Get-Command, everything started to work!

Thanks latkin for quick response!

Comment: After `import-module -name ModuleName` there is not need at all of the `get-command -module Modulename` to use the function/cmdlet from the ModuleName. You have a strange behaviuor not a normal one.

Comment: strange that it would work right after I entered these commands... I'll continue testing and see what is going on.  Once I've imported, will a re-import give me the latest copy of the function?  Maybe i'm not refreshing after each edit?

Comment: re-import a module is done by `import-module -name ModuleName -Force`

Comment: Maybe original import was done when there was nothing in the module, then you are re-importing without `-Force`, so new function(s) is not accessible.  Try with `-Force`, and/or from a fresh Powershell console.

Comment: I think I found it - I used brackets around the function call.... so UserSelectionList( $Options ) as opposed to no brackets.  That and I didnt' have the -Force on the import.

Answer (score 8):

I've encountered the same problem. Steps to reproduce:

- Write a PowerShell script with an `Import-Module` statement
- Execute the script at a PowerShell prompt
- Add a function to the imported module
- Modify the script to call the newly-added function
- Execute the script again, in the same PowerShell session

The error went away after I added the `-Force` argument to `Import-Module`. The `-Force` argument can be removed once the function in the imported module is able to be called.

Note that [latkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366219/latkin) has alluded to this solution in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591281/calling-a-function-within-module-powershell#comment18631768_13591854) to the question. I'm hoping this will make it more visible.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to `Get-Command` if you didn't export the method properly from the module.

At the end of your module put this:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function UserSelectionList
```

Note that it also accepts wild cards, so for example if you have 5 different Get-Some-Value functions that follow a naming convention you could just do

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-*
```

---

Side note on `-Force`: all that does is check if a module is already loaded and, if it is, removes it before continuing with the import. It's the same as saying:

```
Remove-Module userselectionlist.psm1
Import-Module userselectionlist.psm1
```