# Powershell Import-Module fails with DllNotFoundException

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-module

Trying to use http://powershellgac.codeplex.com on another computer with powershell 2.0, using it successfully in powershell 3.0 on my main pc but shows this on the other pc:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable

Manifest AppLocker            {}
Manifest PSDaignostics        {}
Manifest TroubleshootingGPack {}
Manifest Gac                  {}
Manifest Gac                  {}
Manifest Gac                  {}
```

The brackets are all filled on my main pc, why isn't this working? I have set the ExeuctionPolicy to "unrestricted". Still the same error. I have set the $env:PSModulePath correctly on both pcs. (how else would it find the Gac manifest at all)

EDIT: I forgot to add the most important info: When I start the .ps1 script inside Powershell ISE then it works, even on the other pc. 
So clearly there's nothing wrong with the script itself, so I'm clueless.

Answer (score 1):

`-ListAvailable` lists all the modules it can find on your machine, but those modules are not necessarily loaded (using import-module). PowerShell 2.0 does not show the exported commands until a module is loaded, but PowerShell 3.0 does. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354317/how-do-i-retrieve-the-available-commands-from-a-module). If you want to see the exported commands from a loaded module try `Get-Module`.

The results of the command are no reason to believe that the module is not working.

I'm the author of the PowerShell GAC module and I want to thank your for trying it out. Please add the complete error message details when loading the module so we can figure out what the problem is.

Execute `dir ((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:Software\Microsoft\.NetFramework -Name InstallRoot).InstallRoot)` in both the PowerShell console and the ISE and let me know what results you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason it worked now. I really don't know why, the problem will probably turn up again sometime and then I can post the info you wanted.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you find my module useful. Please let me know if I can help you with any other questions or problems you might have.