# Powershell Script to fetch help message for all the functions available in the Module (.psm1)

Tags: powershell

Could someone provide PowerShell script to fetch help message for all the functions from the module (.psm1).

Using `Get-Content` I am able to read the content of `.psm1` file but I was not able to fetch only the help message for all functions available in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below PowerShell Script I able to fetch help message for each function in the module in separate text file with function name.

```
$ModuleName =  'ModuleName' #Specify the Module
$path ="D:\Helpmessage\" #Specify Folder path for each functions help message

Import-Module $ModuleName -Force 

$FunctionName = Get-Command -Module $ModuleName 
$FunctionName = $FunctionName | where {$_.CommandType -eq 'Function'} 

 Foreach ($Function in $FunctionName.Name)
 {
  $result = 
  @("Function $Function `n {"  
  (get-command $Function).Definition
  "}")
  Invoke-expression "$result"
  get-help $Function  | out-file $Path\$Function.txt #Export help message for all the function

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+get+help+about+module&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) produced this handy link

[PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Display Help for Module Cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/07/powertip-use-powershell-to-display-help-for-module-cmdlets/)

> After you have updated your Help in Windows PowerShell 3.0, use the
>   **Get-Command** cmdlet to retrieve all cmdlets from a specific module,
>   pipe the results to the **Foreach-Object** cmdlet, and use the **Get-Help**
>   cmdlet inside the script block.
>
> Following is an example for the **PrintManagement** module:
>
> ```
> Get-Command -Module PrintManagement | Foreach-Object {Get-Help $_.Name -Examples}
> ```
>
> Here is a shorter version of the same command:
>
> ```
> gcm -mo *print* | % {get-help $_.name -ex}
> ```

referencing this answer : [How do I retrieve the available commands from a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354525/5233410)

You would need to first load up the module (.psm1) if it was not imported already. Then you can call the cmdlet like in the example above

```
Import-Module -Name <ModuleName>
Get-Command -Module <ModuleName> | Foreach-Object {Get-Help $_.Name -Examples}
```